# React: Communicating Between Nested Components

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm pretty much new to react. I have been having issues communication between nested react components. I have looked up several react documentations yet to no avail.

How can I communicate endlessly between nested React Components?

Consider the code below

```
//src com2.js
class Com2 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//src com1.js
class Com1 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {e1: "Before"};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e){
    this.setState({e1: "After"})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Com2>
        <Com3>{this.state.e1}</Com3>
        <Com4 clickEvent={this.handleClick}/>
      </Com2>
    );     
  }
}

//src com3.js
class Com3 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//src com4.js
class Com4 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.clickEvent}>click me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

the way my page is set up. com1 is the main class where everything happens

Here I want to update the state e1; when user clicks on the button defined in Com4!

I have tried every thing and it seems not to be working, I am really confused on how to go about this!

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shannon-69inf?file=/src/App.js) and it's working correctly. Are you receiving any errors? You seem to have the right idea–lift state up to a common component.

Comment: Wow. this works really on the sandbox. Let me carefully review my code on my local machine/ Thanks @LMulvey

Comment: Thanks. Spotted my errors. Bless you and stay safe!